# Site Hosted on Amazon S3 Not Displaying Favicon

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, favicon

So I recently started playing around with Amazon S3 and build a small sample web app. I followed the [tutorials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) and my site, including images, are working correctly. I added a `favicon.ico` file to my root directory and referenced this in my `index.html` but no matter what I do I cannot get the favicon to display in a browser search bar, tab, or favorites list.

Note that I used the Bucket Policy permissions provided by the [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) in Step 2.1 - Part 4 to make my objects publicly accessible, and I can also navigate to the link provided by the S3 Bucket that holds my favicon.ico object and I can see it in the browser, so I know the link works.

If the link works, everything in the Bucket is publicly accessible, and the rest of my site works including images, what am I doing wrong?

**File Structure**

[image]

**index.html**

```
...
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
...
```

**Amazon S3 Bucket**

[image]

**Bucket Policy**

[image]

UPDATE: I have also tried removing `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">` completely from my `index.html` and also modifying it to have a `/` in front of `favicon.ico` like so `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">` to no avail.

Comment: First things first: If you just type `http://your.site.url.example.com/favicon.ico` in the browser's address bar, do you see the icon image in the browser window?  Also,  4.2KB favicon file seems excessively large... doesn't it?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot so using `http://your.site.url.example.com/favicon.ico` does work and I have just confirmed after a night of sleep that I am now seeing the favicon in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. Wondering if its a Mac issue? For the file size, I did a 32x32 made in GIMP with transparent background and saved as an ICO as 32 bpp, 8-bit alpha, no palette. What would you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend enabling logging on the bucket and checking whether you see anything unusual, or the request that you believe is being made is in fact being made.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is not an Aws/S3 issue. You can check this by opening the website locally (i.e. from local disk rather than S3) and seeing if the favicon appears. Note that Chrome won't display favicons from locally hosted sites though.

Here a few things to try:

- Clear you browser cache and reload the page
- Run the website locally and open it with FireFox
- Try and use a png favicon instead, in case
  there is a problem with your x-icon

Comment: Chrome was in fact showing my favicon when loading from my local machine, not sure why but I am happy about that. Seems now with my original implementation my favicon is now showing up when hosted on AWS in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari.

Comment: FIreFox showed `favicon.ico` without issue (local or on s3), but would not show on s3.  Changing the app to use `favicon.png` resolved the issue in all scenarios across all browsers

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work by using the full exact URL of the favicon in the s3 bucket.

```html
<link 
  rel="shortcut icon" 
  type="image/icon" 
  href="https://my-s3-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/favicon.ico"
>
```

Cloudfront has permissions to access this file, it just has to know where it is- *no public bucket required.*

If you just do the relative path, i.e. `href="favicon.ico"`, that will resolve to your-www.domain.com/favicon.ico, which is not where the file actually is.

If you're using some kind of bundler, a relative path may work as long as you specify the base path as the url of the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, there is no need to add anything in bucket policy.

1. Once you added your production build resources to S3 > Then give full public access to all your files. Hit next and save. **Remember** you are giving read-only access to the public. Please find the screenshot.

[image]

2. Make sure you check the metadata from favicon like below

[image]

3. Check the permission whether the group you are trying to access have both read and write permissions.

Hope it helps

Comment: Meta data is good. I've seen where people say they click on the object in the Bucket and select More > Make Public, but doing so gives a warning of "Everyone will have access to one or all of the following: read this object, read and write permissions." which sounds like the wrong thing to do. I haven't had to do this with my other image file I'm using to test. AWS docs recommended using the Bucket Policy to give public permission, which I did. Why would I need to give write access to everyone? I'm confused about this especially for security reasons.

Comment: The permission which I have mentioned is the group permission. I will apply the bucket policy and let you know the result soon

Comment: I have checked my resources- if you look at keenly we are giving public access with read-only.

Comment: Hm that is interesting and a different method of granting public read access than using the Bucket Policy per AWS docs. I will keep that in mind. When I added my items originally I left the Manage Public Permissions combo box on `Do not grant public read access to this object(s) (recommended)` and afterwards added the Bucket Policy permissions. Either way, it seems that overnight my favicon is now showing up on Chrome and Firefox without issue, yet not Safari.

Comment: your question has made good awareness of what we did in AWS S3.

Comment: Tried it again. Definitely not. once you done the above configuration. Hit ctrl + f5 - hard refresh. If you still face error then you need to serve via cloud front

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and was curious why one of my pages worked and another did not.
I found that if I set this in the HTML (inside the  tags in the header, all worked well:

```
<meta>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/icon" href="images/favicon.png">
</meta>
```

I also tested with this, and it also worked:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Apparently, if it is not specified, it will try to pull it from amazon.com.

*Note:* In my case, the main bucket is public, however I also put in a bucket policy which restricts the access to a specific CIDR block.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, I updated the content type of my favicon to `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`
and problem resolved.

Also after changing the content you should open you tab in a new incognito window or do empty cache hard reload.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I can confirm that it's some caching issue of Google Chrome. At first I had it like:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

And it didn't work when loaded for AWS as well as when I tried loading directly from file system. So it should be:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

as confirmed by loading from file system. But it still didn't work in Chrome. I also tried all sorts of things before I found the issue on reddit where author said it resolved itself so I decided that should be some caching issue so I tried opening my site in MS Edge and it worked. So I closed all Chrome related processes (including secure shell extension started one) and restarted Chrome and it worked. I bet it's caused by some sort of "web pages loading optimization" feature which caches (more aggressively) meta data parts of your page or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit late, but in case somebody had this issue, in my case, I had to add behavior to CloudFront with path pattern /favicon.ico that would point to my s3 bucket, and that would fix it for me.